# The sum of the bases of $V$ and $V^\perp$ is equal to $n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and the size of the basis of
>   $V$ is $l$ and the size of the basis of $V^\perp$ is $m$, then
>   $l+m=n$.

I was thinking we could have $L:\mathbb{R^m}\rightarrow 0$ be a linear transformation. Then we have $L(V^\perp)=0$ so that $AV^\perp = 0$ is the kernel of $V^\perp$. But I don't know where to go from here. Does the kernel of $V^\perp$ give us information about $m$ that is useful in proving the result?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* consider the orthogonal projection onto $V$. This is a linear transformation. Now compute its image and its kernel.

The orthogonal projection onto $V$ is the linear transformation $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ given by $P(u)=(u\cdot v_1)v_1+\cdots+(u\cdot v_l)v_l$, where $v_1,\dots,v_l$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ and $u\in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Is this $L:\mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^l}$?

Comment: @JoelB, no, $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Can you spell out what the linear transformation is? Sorry, I'm just slightly confused. Is it something like $L(V)=V^\perp$?

Comment: @JoelB, see my edited answer.

Comment: Isn't $u\cdot v_1$ zero for the projection?